# write (byte[] b) optim usage for large byte array

Tags: java, streaming

If I have a large byte array already in memory received from a SOAP response.

I have to write this byte array into an OutputStream.

It is OK just to use write:

```
byte [] largeByteArray=...;

outputstream.write(largeByteArray);

...
outputstream.flush();
...
```

or is better **to split** the bytearray in **small chunks** and to write that to the outputstream?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you've already *got* the large array, then just write it out - if the output stream implementation chooses to chunk it, *it* can make that decision. I can't see a benefit in you doing that for it - which may well make it *less* efficient, if it's able to handle large chunks.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to make this more efficient, I would write the data as you get it rather than building a large byte[] (and waiting until the end to start writing).  If this is an option is it can be faster and more efficient.  However if this is not an option use one large write.

Comment: I would have done the same ...but that byte array comes in the payload of a soap response and that is not streamed...I just received it..and i have to use it like that...

Answer (score 2):

What type of output stream are you using?
There are output streams that can write the array in chunks.
In general I believe if you issue an I/O operation (write) for each single byte, the performance may be poor, because I/O operations are expensive.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of no conceivable reason it would be better without getting truly bizarre and absurd. Generally, if you can pass data between layers in larger chunks without additional effort, then you should do so. Often, it's even worth additional effort to do things that way, so why would you want to put in extra effort to make more work?

Answer (score -2):

If `largeByteArray` is something really large , and write job cost long time , and memory is a considerable condition:

- Split the array to parts, after write one part ,set the part=null, this release the reference of the part ,  would make the JVM/GC the part as soon as possible .
- By split and release , you can do more  write(largeByteArray) job at the same time, before OOM-ERROR occurs.
- Notice:
  during split stage, JVM need double arraysize  memory to do so, but after split, original array will eventually get GC'd ,you are back to using the same amount of memory as before.
- Example: a server has 1GB memory . it can  run max 100 thread that each one holding and sending 10MB data  to client sametime.

  if you use the big 10MB array, memory use is always 1GB,no spare part even all thread has 1MB data not sent.

  my solution is split 10MB to 10*1MB.  after send some MB part , the sent part maybe get JVM/GC .and each thread is costing less average memory in whole life time. so server may run more tasks

Comment: make the JVM gc --is not up to me ...how can i dereference a part of an array ? not sure is efficient copiying in a smaller array..as so on...

Comment: Why? He already has the large array, why use *more* memory creating small sub-copies? and how can he 'release the reference of early part of array'?

Comment: yeah, split array to array of array. set original array=null let jvm finalize it. Then write one by one, after write one, set data(i)=null; after lowlevel stream complete io operation on data(i), jvm may free data(i) array now. if keep data in one large array, the arrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrray can only free after all io completed.  when many job at sametime, oom may occurs. that's trade off, cpu for memory.  i said only if largeByteArray is something really large , and write job cost long time , and memory is a considerable condition .

Comment: try think scene of  10k low speed connections to  a stream server.

Comment: @swanliu Doubling the amount of memory required, and copying all the data, and increasing the number of system calls cannot possibly make anything faster or less memory-intensive. This is all nonsense.

Comment: @EJP . set original array=null  means  jvm  will finalize it.. double space required when split, but then original arrrrrrrrrrray space will free, only split arrayOfarray left in memory for long time use.

Comment: you may know rfc2616, the http1.1 has a  chunked transfer encoding, 'The chunked encoding modifies the body of a message in order to transfer it as a series of chunks, '.  i guess they introduce that standard for the same consideration .

Comment: @swanliu you can't set the original array to null until you've allocated other arrays of the same size and copied all the data. During that time you are using twice as much memory as before, and then when the original array is eventually GC'd you are back to using the same amount of memory as before. And there are still more system calls. *There is absolutely no advantage whatsoever in this technique.* Chunked transfer encoding is not implemented via this technique and in fact has absolutely nothing to do with the point at issue.

Comment: i agree double space required when split. But my point is trade cpu for memerory , where  many task at same time. by using  my technique the server can serve more task before OOM. you do not understand what i was talking about. it's concurrency.

Comment: for example,  a server has 1000000MB memeory. 
 it can run 100000 thread  ,each one  sending 10MB data to client. 
 my solution is split 10MB to 10*1MB, after sometime , all thread has complete 5MB,  
 if you use the big 10MB array, memeory use is still 100000*10MB.  
 But with small array , after send 5MB, memeory use is 100000*(10-5)MB. 
 
 so ,each send task average  memory cost in life time is less. 
 then the admin may raise threadPool size by nearly double,  (1000000MB-10MB)/5MB, before OOM
 
 and ,the 10MB is reserved for the split operation

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3648/discussion-between-swanliu-and-ejp)

Comment: @swanliu There is nothing to discuss. Writes to distinct channels *are* concurrent. Wasting memory and CPU time doesn't help anything. It just makes everything worse.